# Google Drive API JavaScript having trouble getting file properties

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm having trouble getting all images in the root folder in my Google Drive using the Google Drive API. I'm starting simple and getting some info from the first file I retrieve. When I get the ID I get 0By19fyuYeoHHN2M3LWRqRWNucWM, but I have tried other things such as title and thumbnailLink I get undefined. Only thing that seems to work is id and kind. I'm looking here for a list of properties of a file. 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files
Not really sure what is wrong. My scope is 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'.
Thanks in advanced.

Code

```
function retrieveAllFilesInFolder(folderId, callback)
{
    var retrievePageOfChildren = function(request, result)
    {
        request.execute(function(resp)
        {
            result = result.concat(resp.items);

            var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;

            if (nextPageToken)
            {
                request = gapi.client.drive.children.list(
                {
                    'folderId' : folderId,
                    'pageToken': nextPageToken
                });

                retrievePageOfChildren(request, result);
            }
            else 
            {
                callback(result);
            }
        });
    }

    var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.children.list(
    {
        'folderId' : folderId
    });

    retrievePageOfChildren(initialRequest, []);
}

function printToOutdiv(result) 
{
    document.getElementById("outdiv").innerHTML = result[0].id;
}

function GetFilesButton ()
{
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function()   
    {
        retrieveAllFilesInFolder('root',printToOutdiv);
    });
}
```

Edit : Updated code and it works but you can't specify folder.

```
function retrieveAllFiles(callback) 
{
    var retrievePageOfFiles = function (request, result) 
    {
        request.execute(function (resp) 
        {
            result = result.concat(resp.items);

            var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;

            if (nextPageToken) 
            {
                request = gapi.client.drive.files.list(
                {
                    'pageToken': nextPageToken
                });

                retrievePageOfFiles(request, result);
            } 
            else 
            {
                callback(result);
            }
        });
    }

    var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.files.list();

    retrievePageOfFiles(initialRequest, []);
}
```